# How to Release a WPF with a Database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, release

I am using Entity Framework and now want to Release the Software - it has one Data Entity Model attached to it which is hosted on the developing PC as localhost.

**Is there a way I can release this which it will then keep the Database?**

Every time I release it and then open the program crashes; when I release it, I get a red line error on any Database code very quickly which appears and then disappears.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

> *Edit*: Does the Database have to be hosted online?
>
> *Edit*: It does not crash when I run it in debug mode and it works fine
>
> *Edit*: I have moved the .exe file onto my Desktop only (not sure if I had to take the whole release file)
>
> *Edit*: Here is a PrintScreen:

[image: Crashed on Logon]

Comment: You can use localhost for release. Please, show your error.

Comment: I have no error, the program simply just crashes on logon, Ill update with a Gyazo. @Lance

Comment: Updated with an Image - when I try to logon, it crashes - when I remove the Database code and release it, it won't crash on logon - which to me looks asif the Database is not being exported into the App.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework your program will need those assemblies and any others it depends upon in the same folder as the .exe file. Probably explains why it works okay in Debug. Visual Studio copies the dependencies into the output folder for you.

Comment: As you posted that I just copied the release folder to the desktop and it works fine. If you add that as an answer - I can accept it. @JackHughes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework your program will need those assemblies and any others it depends upon in the same folder as the .exe file. Probably explains why it works okay in Debug. Visual Studio copies the dependencies into the output folder for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity now, I can seem to open this Database file in the Release package which is a big security flaw if I am releasing this project to public, is there anyway I can restrict direct access to the file or compile it into the .exe file? It contains sensitive data people could view if not careful (the application requests an API when the user has data access and updates information from an online app so this really needs to be secure).

Comment: With databases like SQLite you can restrict usage via a password. Not by any means foolproof as your code would need to know the password but it could foil an unsophisticated viewer.

Comment: I used an external database instead but thanks a lot!